# Change form label text at runtime

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an HTML label and I would like to change its text at runtime. I know I can use `innerHTML`, which works, but why does it just just append my message in front of the already-set label text.

PHP:

```
<label for="hp_display" id="addToHP_<?php echo $x; ?>"></label><?php echo $addTo; ?>homepage: </label><input type="checkbox" id="hp_display_<?php echo $x; ?>" <?php echo $check; ?> onclick="addToHome('<?php echo md5($product['product_id']); ?>','<?php echo $add; ?>','<?php echo $x; ?>')" />
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function addToHome(id,a,n){
    $.ajax({
        url:'func/addToSlider.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:{type:a,id:id},
        beforeSend: function(){
            document.getElementById('addToHP_'+n).innerHTML = '';
            document.getElementById('addToHP_'+n).innerHTML = 'Updating';
        },
        success:function(e){
            if(e === '1'){
                document.getElementById('addToHP_'+n).innerHTML = '';
                if(a === 'remove'){
                    document.getElementById('addToHP_'+n).innerHTML = 'Add to homepage';
                }else{
                    document.getElementById('addToHP_'+n).innerHTML = 'Remove from homepage';
                }
            }else{
                alert('There has been a server changing your file, please try again');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

It looks complicated, but surely `innerHTML` or JQuery's `.html('')` should replace the text instead of appending the text. I could just refresh page on success of the ajax but I think changing the label text is more user-friendly.

Comment: I think if you're using jquery for what you're describe, you'd want to just use .text()

Answer (score 2):

Your html markup is wrong, you have two closing label elements

```
<label for="hp_display" id="addToHP_<?php echo $x; ?>"></label><?php echo $addTo; ?>homepage: </label>
                                                       ^^^^^^^^                              ^^^^^^^
```

without all the php mark up it is

```
<label>X</label>Y</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have too many `</label>`

```
<label for="hp_display" id="addToHP_<?php echo $x; ?>"></label><?php echo $addTo; ?>homepage: </label>
```

so while the label looks like it is being appended it is actually getting filled for the first time. remove the first `</label>` and problem solved.

should be:

```
 <label for="hp_display" id="addToHP_<?php echo $x; ?>"><?php echo $addTo; ?>homepage: </label>
```

Comment: yeah simple things, should have checked that better.

Comment: it's usually the simple things

Comment: Yeah not the first time probably not the last time, everyday is a learning curve